# How to plot several curves of the same variable for different values of a parameter using R?

Tags: r, plot, system, ode

I am working with an SIR model using R. I need to plot multiple curves of I on the same figure for different values of beta, say for the values of 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, and 0.005. Given below is the code that I have been working with so far. I know this might be a very simple problem, but I am new to R and couldn't find anything helpful yet.

```
library(deSolve)
sir_model <- function(time, variables, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(variables, parameters)), {
    dS <- -beta * I * S
    dI <-  beta * I * S - gamma * I
    dR <-  gamma * I
    return(list(c(dS, dI, dR)))
  })
}
parameters <- c(beta  = 0.001, gamma = 0.3)
initial_values <- c(S = 999, I = 1, R = 0)
time_series <- seq(0, 100)

sir_model_1 <- ode(
  y = initial_values,
  times = time_series,
  func = sir_model,
  parms = parameters
)

sir_model_1 <- as.data.frame(sir_model_1)


with(sir_model_1, { 
  plot(time, I, type = "l", col = "black",
       xlab = "time (days)", ylab = "Number of infections")     
})
```

I tried to use a for loop, but I think I am not doing it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package **deSolve** contains a plotting function that supports to add multiple scenarios. It works directly with the output of `ode` that is a matrix of class `deSolve`. The first argument of the plot function needs to be such a `deSolve` object and the second can be a list of such objects.

This way, it can be run and plotted as follows:

```r
library(deSolve)
sir_model <- function(time, variables, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(variables, parameters)), {
    dS <- -beta * I * S
    dI <-  beta * I * S - gamma * I
    dR <-  gamma * I
    return(list(c(dS, dI, dR)))
  })
}
parameters <- c(beta  = 0.001, gamma = 0.3)
initial_values <- c(S = 999, I = 1, R = 0)
time_series <- seq(0, 100)

run_sir <- function(beta) {
  parameters["beta"] <- beta
  ode(y = initial_values, times = time_series,func = sir_model, parms = parameters)
}

## define scenarios
beta <- 0.001 * 1:5

## run default scenario
run0 <- run_sir(beta = beta[1])
plot(run0)

## run other 4 scenarios
## [-1] means all except the first, that we already have
runs <- lapply(beta[-1], run_sir)

plot(run0, runs, las=1)
legend("bottomright", legend = paste("beta = ", beta), lty=1:5, col=1:5)
```

[image: plot of multiple scenarios]

The `plot.deSolve`function is highly configurable with respect to layout, colors, line types, selection of variables, etc., see help page `?plot.deSolve`.

To plot only selected state variables, one can use the `which` argument, e.g. `which="I"` to plot only the infected.

```r
plot(run0, runs, which="I")
```

Some examples about plotting **deSolve** outputs can be found in the [tutorial slides](http://desolve.r-forge.r-project.org/user2014/tutorial.pdf) in section "Plotting".

Comment: Hey tpetzoldt, thank you so much. This is exactly what I wanted. Could you also please explain how to get the plot for only the variable I? I mean the one in the middle.

Comment: This is what I meant with "selection of variables". You can use: `plot(run0, runs, which="I")` where `"I" ` is the name of the state variable that you want.

Answer (score 2):

We could wrap the code in a function and loop over the sequence of beta values, and `plot`.  If we need to do this in a single plot window, modify the `par`

```
par(mfrow = c(5, 1))
lapply(seq(0.001, length.out = 5, by = 0.001), f1)
```

where

```
f1 <- function(beta) {

parameters <- c(beta  = beta, gamma = 0.3)
initial_values <- c(S = 999, I = 1, R = 0)
time_series <- seq(0, 100)

sir_model_1 <- ode(
  y = initial_values,
  times = time_series,
  func = sir_model,
  parms = parameters
)

sir_model_1 <- as.data.frame(sir_model_1)


with(sir_model_1, { 
  plot(time, I, type = "l", col = "black",
       xlab = "time (days)", main = beta, ylab = "Number of infections")     
})

}
```

-output

[image]

---

In case we want to loop over the column names, use the formula method

```
par(mfrow = c(3, 1))
lapply(names(sir_model_1)[-1], function(nm) 
   plot(reformulate("time", response = nm), data = sir_model_1, main = nm,
      type = "l", col = "black",
        xlab = "time (days)", ylab = "Number of infections"))
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Hi akrun, thanks a lot. This is great, I didn't know this method. Thanks for teaching me that approach. However, what I was actually meaning to do was something like in the figure linked below. Could you please take a look? Apologies if I wasn't being clear enough in my original post. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/709633-plotting-multiple-values-of-a-parameter-on-same-figure

Comment: @Hew123 your original question didn't had that link, so it was not clear what you wanted

Comment: Yeah, I am so sorry about that. However, the confusion led me to learn something new and even more useful. The way that you have plotted the graphs is also something that I have been wanting to do, though not the focus of this question. So, thanks a lot!